# How to Update CSS Property in external style sheet via Laravel?

Tags: php, css, laravel, laravel-5

I am working on a project where i am allowing the user to change theme settings i.e colors, design etc from Admin Panel. I want the user to just enter the color hex code and that will change the linked properties in the view. What i tried to do is

In the view:

```
<style>
button.submitform:hover, button.submitform:focus{
    background: {{ $customizer->global_lite_colorcode}} !important;
}
</style>
```

This solution work perfect but it has to be inline or in the html file, but i want to use externel css file.And this style i.e `button.submitform` lives in external css file called `main.css` . I want the laravel variable to change that property in there. How can i do this ?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that your css file `main.css` can parse notation of Laravel `{{}}`. Of course, if you must style pseudo classes like `hover` or `focus`,  I have an idea about this, I think you can set a fixed style firstly:

```
button.submitform__red:hover, button.submitform__red:focus{
    background: red !important;
}
```

And dynamically bind style with `{{}}` like this:

```
<button>
    <div class="submitform__{{$customizer->global_lite_colorcode}}" />
</button>
```

js way:

```
document.querySelectorAll('.submitform__{{$customizer->global_lite_colorcode}}')[0].style['background'] = '{{$customizer->global_lite_colorcode}}';
```

Comment: If you really have to update color, how about using `mouseover` or `mouseout` to listen `hover` event, and `focus` or `blur` for `focus` event.

Comment: Whatever is the event but i want to update it via laravel variable in the externel css file. @PuiMan Cheui

Answer (score 1):

Since you are dealing with a User (who is probably logged-in), you can very easily create CSS Styles based on the User-id and then load the style Dynamically in the view based on which user is logged-in.

**STEP 1: USING USER ID TO CREATE A CSS FILE**

```
<?php

    // THIS IS AN ACTION IN YOUR CONTROLLER THAT HANDLES THE PROCESSING OF THE 
    // USER-SETTINGS FORM...
    public function saveUserSetting(Request $request){
        // OBTAIN THE $userID YOUR WAY...
        $userDataPath  = __DIR__ . "/../../../public/css/user_data"; 

        // BUILD THE CSS TO BE ADDED TO USERS CUSTOM CSS FILE
        // BASED ON HIS SETTINGS...
        // $customizer = //<== GET THE $customizer OBJECT
        $css        = "button.submitform:hover, button.submitform:focus\{\n";
        $css       .= "background: " . $customizer->global_‌​lite_colorcode . " !important;\n"; 
        $css       .= "\}\n"

        // IF USER-SPECIFIC CSS FILE DOES NOT EXIST, WE CREATE IT,
        // OTHERWISE WE JUST GET ITS CONTENT AND APPEND NEW STYLES TO IT.. 
        if(!file_exists($userDataPath . "/user_{$userID}.css")){
              file_put_contents($userDataPath . "/user_{$userID}.css", $css);         
        }else{
            $data = file_get_contents($userDataPath . "/user_{$userID}.css");
            if(!stristr($data, $css) ){$data.= $css;}
            file_put_contents($userDataPath . "/user_{$userID}.css", $data); 
        }

        // DO OTHER THINGS...
    }
```

Then on the View, make sure you have created a section called "stylesheets" (for example) in your Master-File (That is; if you are using Template inheritance). Your Main Layout File would contain something like below within the < head > section.

```
@yield("stylesheets")
```

Then on the actual View File, you can dynamically add the User's Custom Style-Sheet based on the ID of the logged-in User like so:

```
@extends('layouts.app')

    @section('stylesheets')
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="{{ URL::asset('css/bootstrap.min.css') }}" />
        <!-- THIS WILL LOAD ONLY THE USER'S CUSTOM CSS -->
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="{{ URL::asset('css/user_data/user_' . $userID . ".css") }}" />
    @endsection
```

However; it is important to note that in this approach, the data has to first be saved and written to File before you can see any changes...  you wouldn't have an instant response of seeing your style applied immediately. If you need such Functionality, you may consider integrating Javascript.

Another way would be to gather all the Front-End Settings that the User specified in the Form, and store them as part of the users Table like under the `column_name` `settings` in either serialized or json_encoded format. This means that, once you fetch the Logged-in User Information, you can generate a CSS using the information stored in the `settings`....

Comment: I appreciate your answer but i have only one user in the APP which can be updated if the owner of APP wants to. The question is how i want to replace the External CSS property with a variable, that variable will be coming from database as i mentioned in the question  `background: {{ $customizer->global_lite_colorcode}} !important;` so how i do that?

Comment: @lftikharuddin The Post was updated. Do you have access to $customizer in your controller? Well, guess Yes. You can use the `$customizer->global_‌​lite_colorcode` within the Controller to create the CSS in question.

Comment: I don't want that in Controller @Poiz i want to change css property in external css file.

Answer (score 1):

This for sure can be done in an external file, but **it won't be an external `.css` file;** it will be a `.blade.php` file that contains any css styling, similar to the way you're doing it above. The issue is that since the property `global_lite_colorcode` is attached to a `php` variable `$customizer`, it cannot be parsed in a plain `.css` file.

On your view file, include a `<style>` tag the same way you are currently doing, and use the `@include()` blade command to pull in an external php file:

```
<style>
@include("views.custom.themes")
</style>
```

Specify a valid path to a `.blade.php` file using `.` notation, and in that file, include your "pseudo-inline" css:

```
button.submitform:hover, button.submitform:focus {
    background: {{ $customizer->global_lite_colorcode}} !important;
}
<!-- Any other style tags that rely on php variables -->
```

As long as `$customizer` is accessible in the view file that calls the `@include` function, the code in the included file can also access it.

This is a bit of workaround to using an external `.css` file, but should work for your needs.

Comment: Again that is not external css file, which lives in public directory.

Comment: Yes, I know, but you'll never be able to parse a `php` variable in a plain `.css` file, and even if you did, you'd have a hard time updating the `.css` file to only affect the current user.

Comment: may be there is a way let's see.